# How to reset mariadb password in docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I forgot my password for mariadb running in my docker-compose environment.
Of course resetting the password can be achieved by exec -it into the container and entering:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

and change the password with:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SET PASSWORD FOR 'your_user'=PASSWORD('YOUR_PASSWORD');
```

However in order for mysqld_safe to work the mariadb service has to be stopped. Somehow I cannot stop my mariadb service in the container.

```
root@d266a0667297:/# service mariadb stop
 * Stopping MariaDB database server mariadbd                             [fail]
```

How can I stop mariadb in my docker container in order to then use mysqld_safe to reset the password?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

1. Start my mariadb container with docker-compose and overriding the CMD of the mariadb dockerfile with bash like so:

   sudo docker-compose run database bash
   service --status-all should now show mariadb as not running.

Then change the password:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SET PASSWORD FOR 'wikiuser'=PASSWORD('XRtmkhdMXriIu2VvZ8T');
```

FLUSH PRIVILEGES is used to tell the server to reload the grant tables so that account-management statements work as described here (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a config file with:

```
[mariadb]
init-file=/vol/reset.sql
```

ref: [init-file](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#init_file)

To your container and include the `SET PASSWORD ...` in that file. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` aren't needed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I did a bit of research but I cannot exactly figure out how your solution works. Could you provide some more details? Thank you!